# Join 2 formulas to check 2 cells (Excel 2007)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 formulas that work fine on there own:

- =IF(E2="","N",IF(E2>B2,"Y","N"))
- =IF(F2="","N",IF(F2>B2,"Y","N"))

They first check to see if the cell is blank, and if not they check if one date is greater that the other and if it is it adds Y if not N

However, I would like to join them together so that the results shows in 1 cell and not 2, but I can't work it out.
I know I have to use AND/OR, but I can work out the sequence.

So if either one has a date > than the other it will show a Y
If both are blank it will show an N

Could someone help me please?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
=IF(AND(LEN(E2&F2)>0,OR(E2>B2,F2>B2)),"Y","N")
```

Comment: Interesting use of LEN I didn't think of that. However, for some reason it is not evaluating the date formula correctly as it is showing a Y when the date in E2 is not greater than B2, when it should be showing a N. The Y should show when E2 or F2 are greater than B2. In my test E2 has a date (which is <B2and F2 is blank, in case that helps.

Comment: You might be dealing with *text-that-looks-like-dates* then. Maybe add a screenshot. I can't reproduce that.

Comment: how do I add a screen shot?

Comment: You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63289435/edit) your question.

Comment: Is `F2` truly blank, or is it a formula that returns a blank string `""`?

Comment: Easy when you know how :) You can see that G4 should be a N, as the date is less than B4 and F4 is blank, so either date is > than B4. When I add my single formulas they work fine so I don't think there is any thing in the blank cell

Comment: Another question - do your dates have time components too? If you put in two new cells `=G4>B4` and `=F4>B4`, what are the results?

Comment: I've updated the image to show that my 2 separate formulas work fine, in columns H & I. Any Y in either H or I is marking the whole row to be deleted.

Comment: But if `F4` contains a blank string, then the formula will return `N`. What does `=F4>B4` return?

Comment: Using my single formula an N because it first checked if it was blank, in which case it adds the N. =IF(F4="","N",IF(F4>B4,"Y","N"))

Comment: In a new cell, put `=F4>B4` and please report back on the result.

Comment: It is showing as =TRUE. There was a formula in the cell and I had used Paste Special = Values to clear it, so it must think that something if there. When I select the cell and click the delete button it goes to FALSE

Comment: If you had a formula that returned a blank string and you Paste Special = Values, the blank string is maintained in the cell. Your option is to either clean that column, or to adjust the formula.